# Broker Transport Failure while connection to kafka producer

Tags: node.js, ssl, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

From Node.js application I am trying to connect to Apache Kafka broker using node-rdkafka client .Since the kafka broker lists are SSL enabled hence configuring the node-rdkafka producer with ssl options as below :

I have already tried with different valid certificates and keys tried adding CA also using the option `ssl.ca.certificate:<CA-location>`
but still no luck.

Searched in librdkafka github page and found one similar issue where is the proposed solution was to use `api.verison.request:false` , tried this also but no luck Still getting the same error

> Error: broker transport failure

Tried using another kafka client named no-kafka with the same ssl certificate and keys to connect to the same broker lists and able to establish the connection .

We have to use node-rdkafka only.

The producer configuration using node-rdkafka :

```
var producer = new Kafka.Producer({
    'debug':'All',
    'metadata.broker.list': 'comma separated list of ssl enabled broker hosts and port',
    'dr_cb': true,
    'security.protocol': 'ssl',
    'ssl.certificate.location': path.join(__dirname, 'server.crt'),
    'ssl.key.location': path.join(__dirname, 'server.key'),
    'ssl.ca.location' : path.join(__dirname,'DigiCertSHA2SecureServerCA-int.cer'),
  });
```

I expect a `SUCCESS MESSAGE` saying connection set up, but the actual result is `Error : Broker transport Failure`

Comment: I had similar issue with the python one, which is also on librdkafka. The trick worked is to use `pem` for the certificates and force using system ssl libraries.